# set architecture for ios apps via cordova / phonegap build process

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

Due to certain plugins I have to set architecture for my cordova iOS app to `armv7`. But everytime I build the I have to use X-Code to do that.

Is there a way I can automate this process in `cordova build` or `cordova compile` phase

Answer (score 0):

@Sushant,
if you are using *Phonegap Build*, then you might be able to use `deployment-target` in your [preferences in config.xml](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_preferences.md.html#Preferences).

> This sets the IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET in the build, which tranlsates to the MinimumOSVersion in the ipa Propertly List.

Comment: Sorry but I want to set the architecture like ``armv7`` not the deployment target

Comment: @Sushant did you find solution?

Comment: @Chielarck I end up using Phonegap online build, I dont remember much about it

Answer (score 0):

@Sushant,

Perhaps we've missed a few fine points here.

According to iOS docs

*Device Compatibility*
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html

> Important: If you require a capability listed in bold, you must build your app as a fat binary (armv6 and armv7) or require a minimum iOS version of 4.3 or later. See the individual device tables for a specific key requirement.

So one way to deal with your issue it to set your *iOS version of 4.3*

Next, it appears you need to Add and attribute to your *Info.plist* the following items

- UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities=arm7

You can do this by extending your *config.xml* via the [gap:config-file](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_config_file_element.md.html#Config%20File%20Elements) attribute.

So the only question that remains, is will that work?

The people that can best answer that are at the "[official forum](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi)" for phonegap.

Best of Luck,
Jesse